# Counting the number of k-tuples

Tags: combinatorics

$A$ is a set with $n$ elements, and $k$ is an natural number, given to us.
if we know that: $T_1$ is a subset of $T_2$, $T_2$ is a subset of $T_3$, \dots , $T_{k-1}$ is a subset of $T_k$, then how many $k$-tuple like $(T_1,T_2,\cdots,T_k)$ can be found?
what if instead of this condition, we know that these $T_i$'s are disjoint?
(each $T_i$ is a subset of $A$).

Comment: Can some of the $T_i$ be empty?

Comment: what does $A$ have to do with any of this?

Comment: @TokenToucan I guess so, there's no condition in the problem forcing us to assume otherwise.

Comment: @DavidP i'm sorry i forgot to mention that each Ti is a subset of A, I've edited the question. Thanks

Comment: If $T_k$ has $N(k)$ elements then it has $2^{N(k)}$ possible subsets. Now, $N(k)$ can range from $0$ to $n$. This should give you an inductive path to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the first problem: Let $S_1=T_1$, let $S_2=T_2\setminus T_1$, let $S_3=T_3\setminus T_2$, and so on up to $S_k$. Let $S_{k+1}=A\setminus T_k$. There are just as many ways to pick the $S_i$ as there are *functions* from the set $A$ to the set $\{1,2,\dots,k,k+1\}$.